# Cat D11 bulldozer - should the plough and the frame be connected?

Tags: technic

I’ve completed this and now have some remedial work to do! Can I please check though, are the two parts at the back (the ‘plough’ and the ‘frame’ with the ‘pistons’ on) supposed to be connected in any way? I haven’t connected them but it seems like they should be.

Answer (score 7):

Step 925 indicates there are four attachment points for the plow. I'd suggest checking your model against this, making sure each point lines up.

[image: step 925]

Comment: Thank you. I ended up rebuilding. I'd put two L shaped pieces on pointing down rather than up hence I couldn't link the back parts up properly. All good now :-)